# R - For loop for splitting column's text to new columns

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 10 data frames which include climate data. Column no 1, is "date" column the class of which is character. The *date* format is "1/5/19". I want to separate this column into 3 other columns using a for loop for all my data frames. At first, I've created a vector named "onomata" which contains the data frame names:

```
onomata <- c("agia_paraskeui","ano_liosia","athens_gazi","marina",
         "kifisia","marousi","nea_smyrni","patisia","peristeri",
         "psychico")
```

Then I used the "separate" function from *tidyr* package, and I tested the function for one data frame:

```
agia_paraskeui <- separate(agia_paraskeui, col = date,
                         into = c("day","month","year"), sep = "/")
```

It worked as it should be, and then I tried to apply that to all data frames by using the next for loop:

```
    for(i in onomata){
  i <- separate(i, col = date,
                        into = c("day","month","year"), sep = "/")
}
```

It didn't work. Instead I received the following error message:

*"Error in UseMethod("separate_") :
no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"*

What do you think is the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it needs to be applied on a loop, use `map`.   The objects names are string.  We need to `get` the value of the objects.  If there are more than one, use `mget` and it returns the value of the objects in a `list`.  Loop over the `list`, and apply `separate`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
map(mget(onomata), ~ separate(.x, col = date,
    into = c("day","month","year"), sep = "/"))
```

---

Also, with a loop

```
out <- vector('list', length(onomata))
for(i in seq_along(onomata)) {
   out[[i]] <- separate(get(onomata[i]), col = date,
    into = c("day","month","year"), sep = "/")
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked, and your explanation is very helpful in order to repeat a similar process in the future !!!